# jsf h:inputFile converter?

Tags: file-upload, converters, jsf-2.2

I tried to create a converter to a h:inputFile tag in jsf. What happend was that the converters getAsObject was called correctly but the returned object doesnt seems to be used in the tag. It still uses the unconverted.

So is it even possible to use converters for the h:inputFile?

**UPDATE:** I use netbeans 8 with glassfish 4 to run the code.  A code sample was requested so here it is.

The converter implements the *javax.faces.convert.Converter* interface as I do not know if there is a special converter for files:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageConverter implements Converter{

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println("ImageConverter getAsObject:" +value); // this is how I know its called
        return new ImageCanvas(); 
      } 

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
         System.out.println("ImageConverter getAsString called: "+value.toString()); // just do it
        return "";
    }


}
```

I am aware that the **value** parameter in **getAsObject** will not include the file's content, but the method should atleast be called because the **converter** attribute for the **h:inputFile** tag is allowed. The **ImageCanvas** class contains no magic so it should not cause any issues.

Here is the jsf page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">
    <h:body>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <h:inputFile value="#{submitAsImageCanvas.image}" converter="#{imageConverter}"/>
            <h:commandButton  value="submit" action="#{submitAsImageCanvas.submit()}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the viewScoped bean which expect the **image** property to be a **ImageCanvas**:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SubmitAsImageCanvas implements Serializable{

    private ImageCanvas image;

    public ImageCanvas getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(ImageCanvas image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("Submit called");
    }

}
```

This is what netbeans outputs when I request the jsf page and then submit a file:

```
FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException caught during processing of     UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4 : UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt3-j_idt4, Message=javax.el.ELException: /uploadConverterImageCanvas.xhtml @8,94 value="#{submitAsImageCanvas.image}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert File name=test.txt, StoreLocation=%USERPATH%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GF_4.0\domain1\generated\jsp\AdApp\upload__6fff2383_14717f72869__7ff1_00000200.tmp, size=4bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=j_idt3-j_idt4 of type class org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem to class model.ad.ImageCanvas
FATAL:   javax.el.ELException: /uploadConverterImageCanvas.xhtml @8,94 value="#{submitAsImageCanvas.image}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert File name=test.txt, StoreLocation=%USERPATH%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GF_4.0\domain1\generated\jsp\AdApp\upload__6fff2383_14717f72869__7ff1_00000200.tmp, size=4bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=j_idt3-j_idt4 of type class org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem to class model.ad.ImageCanvas
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.ELException: /uploadConverterImageCanvas.xhtml @8,94 value="#{submitAsImageCanvas.image}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert File name=test.txt, StoreLocation=%USERPATH%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GF_4.0\domain1\generated\jsp\AdApp\upload__6fff2383_14717f72869__7ff1_00000200.tmp, size=4bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=j_idt3-j_idt4 of type class org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem to class model.ad.ImageCanvas
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:867)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1254)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /uploadConverterImageCanvas.xhtml @8,94 value="#{submitAsImageCanvas.image}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert File name=test.txt, StoreLocation=%USERPATH%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GF_4.0\domain1\generated\jsp\AdApp\upload__6fff2383_14717f72869__7ff1_00000200.tmp, size=4bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=j_idt3-j_idt4 of type class org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem to class model.ad.ImageCanvas
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:139)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert File name=test.txt, StoreLocation=%USERPATH%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GF_4.0\domain1\generated\jsp\AdApp\upload__6fff2383_14717f72869__7ff1_00000200.tmp, size=4bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=j_idt3-j_idt4 of type class org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem to class model.ad.ImageCanvas
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:473)
    at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.convertToType(EvaluationContext.java:166)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:235)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert File name=test.txt,     StoreLocation=%USERPATH%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GF_4.0\domain1\generated\jsp\AdApp\upload__6fff2383_14717f72869__7ff1_00000200.tmp, size=4bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=j_idt3-j_idt4 of type class org.apache.catalina.fileupload.PartItem to class model.ad.ImageCanvas
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:417)
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:77)
    ... 43 more
```

In other words, is it telling me that it did not try to use my converter as the converters **getAsObject** method was never called(because the system prints is not called)?

So I tried to answer that question simply by changing the class of property **image** from **ImageCanvas** to **Part** in the bean **SubmitAsImageCanvas**:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SubmitAsImageCanvas implements Serializable{

    private Part image;

    public Part getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Part image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("Submit called");
    }

}
```

So here is what netbeans:

```
Info:   Submit called
Info:   ImageConverter getAsString called: File name=test.txt, StoreLocation=%USERPATH%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GF_4.0\domain1\generated\jsp\AdApp\upload__6fff2383_14717f72869__7ff1_00000204.tmp, size=4bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=j_idt3-j_idt4
```

Ok, no exceptions and **getAsObject** is not called so it never tries to convert it to an object. The page refresh after the submit and the **getAsString** is called to give the **value** attribute of the tag to a string right?

Why do I want to use converters with files? I do not want to do the converting inside the view beans setters/getters because converters divides code and makes these beans clean and simple. Also I want to "convert" the file into an image. **Part** object is not serializable(?) and I will work with small files that might be sent to remote beans.

Back to my question, is converters supported with files? Is it just something that came a long when extending a class? WHY IS THERE A **CONVERTER** ATTRIBUTE FOR FILEINPUT?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, I have added the code. Have I misunderstood the converter usage?